# Service to check if an email address is valid

Tags: webapp-rec, email

Is there any online service to check if a given email address is valid? I don't want to use my private email address to verify an email address by sending a trial message and waiting for a non-delivery message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Verify Email Address](http://verify-email.org/) or the checker from [IP-Address.org](http://www.ip-address.org/verify/email-checker.php).

Comment: [verify-email.org](http://verify-email.org/) fails but [IP-Address.org](http://www.ip-address.org/verify/email-checker.php) succeeds. I tried my corporate email address on both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[BriteVerify](http://www.briteverify.com) sounds like what you're looking for. It offers a few different levels of verification, like scanning to determine if an email address is from a valid domain, and also verifying it against public social profile information to be sure it's valid.